# impala-shell just hangs when invoked in cli

Tags: impala

```
root@master:/usr/lib# impala-shell

/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf8)

Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
```

Then it hangs here. Who know how to diagnose this problem?

Impala related service have been started.

```
root@master:/usr/lib# ps -ef | grep impala

root      7551     1  0 05:46 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/impala/sbin/impalad

impala   11328     1  0 06:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/impala/sbin/statestored -log_dir=/var/log/impala -state_store_port=24000

impala   11395     1  0 06:45 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/impala/sbin/catalogd -log_dir=/var/log/impala

root     11703     1  0 06:55 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto impala
```

/tmp/impalad.ERROR:

```
Log file created at: 2016/06/14 07:09:31
Running on machine: master
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
E0614 07:09:31.558585 11834 logging.cc:120] stderr will be logged to this file.
E0614 07:09:32.755619 11918 thrift-server.cc:176] ThriftServer 'backend' (on port: 22000) exited due to TException: Could not bind: Transport endpoint is not connected
E0614 07:09:32.755651 11834 thrift-server.cc:165] ThriftServer 'backend' (on port: 22000) did not start correctly
E0614 07:09:32.755666 11834 impalad-main.cc:78] ThriftServer 'backend' (on port: 22000) did not start correctly
```